# Convert hex-timestamp back

Tags: javascript, html, timestamp, hex, number-systems

I often see timestamp values in a form-field written in hex:

```
<input type="hidden" name="timestamp" value="b1a38fee9509c100228be1dc5d379cd9">
```

How can I calculate them back to something readable? First I thought about making Byte-Chunks and then calculating them into decimals, but that didn't make much sence to me:

```
b1   a3  8f  ee  95  09  c1  00  22  8b  e1  dc  5d  37  9c  d9
177 163 143 238 149 009 193 000 034 139 225 220 093 055 156 217
```

Thank you

Comment: 128 bits long. Looks like it could be an MD5 hash of a timestamp.

Comment: So why would anyone hash a timestamp? Passwords yes, but timestamps...

Comment: It could be some form of security through obscurity. Perhaps an attempt to hide how the timestamp is generated.